# Rails routing - redirection with block AND status code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Well, I've been hitting my head against a brick wall with this one - any help much appreciated!

I'm redirecting old urls and for the most part that's easy and working well, e.g.:

```
match '/pages/holiday-specials/', :to => redirect( "/accommodation", :status => 301 )
```

However, I need a special catch-all rule that needs to do some regex checking. This works well EXCEPT I can't get it to pass the status. This redirects and does what I need but doesn't send the 301 status:

```
match '/*:path', :to => redirect( lambda { |params| "/operator/#{/[^\d](\d+)([^\d]|$)/.match(params[:path])[1]}" }, :status => 301)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: On a side note, I believe `301` is the default status code when redirecting a route, so you should not need to set it manually. We were aiming for a `302` and ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 10):

Move the block outside the method parentheses, as follows:

```
match '/*:path', :to => redirect(:status => 301) { |params| "/operator/#{/[^\d](\d+)([^\d]|$)/.match(params[:path])[1]}" }
```

or split it over multiple lines:

```
match '/*:path', :to => redirect(:status => 301) do |params|
  "/operator/#{/[^\d](\d+)([^\d]|$)/.match(params[:path])[1]}"
end
```